# Не работает кнопка Назад Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Попытался сделать бота в телеграмм с кнопкой возврата в начальное меню но ничего не получается, и не могу понять в чем ошибка. сможет кто помочь?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    detailes = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе', callback_data='detailes_1')
    services = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Услуги', callback_data='services_2')
    instruction = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Инструкция', callback_data='instruction_3')
    markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствуем вас! В магазине PayMent out!\nВыберите информацию для '
                                      'отображения: ', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'detailes_1':
            markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            back = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад в меню', callback_data='back_1')
            markup1.add(back)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню'",
                             reply_markup=markup1)
        elif call.data == 'back_1':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Как так получается что вы в reply клавиатуру засовываете inline кнопки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312230/oleksandrigo так если я вставлю callback_data в кнопки Keyboard то PyCharm будет callback_data подчеркивать желтым и писать Unexpected argument

Answer (score 0):

Может потому что у вас кнопка возвращает `back_1`, а вы ловите `back`?

UPD.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    detailes = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе', callback_data='detailes_1')
    services = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Услуги', callback_data='services_2')
    instruction = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Инструкция', callback_data='instruction_3')
    markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствуем вас! В магазине PayMent out!\nВыберите информацию для '
                                      'отображения: ', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    if call.data == 'detailes_1':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        back = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад в меню', callback_data='back_1')
         markup1.add(back)
         bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                             "Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню'",
                             reply_markup=markup1)
    elif call.data == 'back_1':
         bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)
```

Comment: Изменил но все равно не выходит

Comment: Что именно вы изменили?

Comment: Лучше скиньте код, который получился нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1427633/edit)

Comment: @oleksandrigo, bbcode `[edit]` в комментарии под ответом формирует ссылку на редактирование **этого ответа**, а отнюдь не вопроса. (автору вопроса именно в свой вопрос надо вставить запрошенный код).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin тоесть чтобы автор мог при нажатии на кнопку править свой вопрос, мне нужно было сделать комментарий с этой ссылкой конкретно под вопросом?

Comment: @oleksandrigo, ага.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
    
    if call.data == 'detailes_1':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        back = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад в меню', callback_data='back_1')
        markup1.add(back)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню'",
                             reply_markup=markup1)
    elif call.data == 'back_1':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)
```