# Телеграм бот не реагирует на нажатие на кнопку в диалоге

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Написал код для бота в телегерам. Ввожу команду `/start` и после проблема в том, что нажимаю на кнопку 'Детали о сервисе' и ничего не происходит:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
      markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
      detailes = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Детали о сервисе', callback_data='detailes_1')
      services = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Услуги', callback_data='services_2')
      instruction = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Инструкция', callback_data='instruction_3')
      markup.add(detailes, services, instruction)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствуем вас! В магазине PayMent out!\nВыберите информацию для '
                                        'отображения: ', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'detailes_1':
           markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
           back = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад в меню', callback_data='back_1')
           markup1.add(back)
           bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"Выберите,что вам нужно,если хотите вернуться в меню просто нажмите кнопку 'Назад в меню'",reply_markup=markup1)
        elif call.data == 'back_1':
           bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=None)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает кнопка Назад Aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1427633/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4-aiogram)

Comment: Я ведь уже ответил в чем ваша проблема.

Comment: oleksandrigo так а как callback_data вствить в KeyboardButton, если я вставлю то будет писать Unexpected argument

Comment: Потому что реплай клавиатуры не умеют в колбеки

Comment: Этот вопрос удалите, это дубликат. Перейдите в предыдущую и там решайте её